# QGIS3 - length3D strange results

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, attribute-table, length

I am using QGIS 3.32. My project and data are in EPSG:4236-WGS84.
I used `drape (set Z value from raster)` the line layer onto an elevation grid, resulting in a Line (MultiLineStringZ). On this layer, I created a new field 'lengthZ'. Then using the Field Calculator, I calculated lengthZ with this expression:

```
length3D($geometry)
```

Also added a field 'meters' and calculated with `$length`.
The lengthZ values in the attribute table are confusing. The lengthZ units should be in meters, but given 3D topography, there's no way 3D distances can be shorter than 2D distances. So, I did something wrong.. but what?

| meters | lengthZ |
| --- | --- |
| 710 | 91 |
| 692 | 43 |
| 4964 | 507 |
| 3459 | 347 |
| 1796 | 213 |
| 54 | 3 |
| 1051 | 63 |

Comment: Did you try to transform your data to ortogonal coordinate system and then calc lengthZ()?

Comment: Projecting from EPSG:4236 to an orthogonal coordinate system solved my problem.  Thanks so much!